# Here-document not working properly on shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document, dialog

I have two files: `server.sh` and `client.sh`, the server sends the following text to the client

### client.sh

```
porta_cliente=5678
porta_servidor=8765

nc -l $porta_cliente | sh
```

### server.sh

```
porta_cliente=5678
porta_servidor=8765

nc $ip $porta_cliente <<-EOF
        dialog --stdout --backtitle 'Bem vindo ao SEPA 0.1' --title 'Menu inicial' --menu 'Escolha uma opção:' 0 0 0 \
        Cadastrar 'Criar um novo usuário' \
        Entrar 'Fazer login com sua conta' \
        Sair 'Encerrar o SEPA' > logservidor

        # WORKING FINE UNTIL HERE!

        case `cat logservidor` in
                "Cadastrar")
                        echo "LOG: case is being executed" > /dev/tcp/"$ip"/"$porta_servidor"
                        dialog --stdout --msgbox 'CADASTRAR' 0 0 > /dev/tcp/"$ip"/"$porta_servidor"
                ;;
                "Entrar")
                        echo "LOG: case is being executed"
                        echo "LOGIN SELECIONADO" > /dev/tcp/"$ip"/"$porta_servidor"
                ;;
                "Sair")
                        echo "LOG: case is being executed"
                        echo "SAIR SELECIONADO" > /dev/tcp/"$ip"/"$porta_servidor"
                ;;
        esac
EOF
```

As you can see, the server sends a text (interpreted as multiple lines of commands) to the client through netcat, on these commands, i'm trying to pass the user input to a specific file, and then, use a case statement to check if that user input is `Cadastrar`, `Entrar` or `Sair`, the first dialog part is working fine, but the `case 'cat log servidor' in` is not being executed (even with `bash -x server.sh` i couldn´t find what is causing this problem)

Comment: Of course `bash -x server.sh` won't give any errors as the server only pipes the text to the client. Copy the part between the EOF (the here-doc) and manually insert it on the client. Run it from there and you'll most propably find the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `dialog` command, whose output is redirected to the file `logservidor`, is being executed at the remote end.  But the line that's supposed to read its output:

```
case `cat logservidor` in
```

...is being executed locally, while constructing the here-document.  That's because here-documents perform various expansions, including command substitution, at the time they're defined.

You could delay this expansion (so that it only happens when the script is executed) by quoting `EOF`:

```
nc $ip $porta_cliente <<-"EOF"
```

But that would also delay expansion of variables in the script such as `$ip`.  If you want those variables to be expanded immediately, but the `cat` command executed later, you could escape the backticks:

```
case \`cat logservidor\` in
```

You could also debug the problem yourself by looking at the final command before you try to send and execute it.  Replace the first line with

```
cat > tmp-doc <<-EOF
```

Then look in `tmp-doc` to see what would have been sent over `nc`.

Comment: Thank you a lot @JigglyNaga, but when i try to put the dialog insidea variable, like `menu=\$(dialog --stdout --msgbox 'Hello World!' 0 0)` the `case` still not working, any workaround?

Comment: @HenriqueHBR "still not working" is not a useful description.  You'll have to update your question/start a new one to show exactly what you did and what happened.  Did you try redirecting the here-doc into a temporary file first?

Comment: Already solved, i quoted every single $ and ' with \

Comment: @HenriqueHBR Just like I mentioned in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785835/here-document-not-working-properly-on-shell-script#comment84576457_48785835) version of this question, merely quoting the tag will prevent any expansions.

Comment: @PesaThe In this case, it´s better to quote only some parts of the text, i was trying to quote everything, but it gave me some errors

Comment: @HenriqueHBR If you don't want expansions to take place, you will have to quote every single one. Why not just quote the tag?

Comment: @PesaThe As i said, i was trying to quote the whole tag, but there were some characters in the text that shouldn´t be quoted